# How to open iphone project's .m files on windows operating system

Tags: iphone, windows

I am iphone application developer, I am just new into it. At work i use Mac for development which is quite obvious, but at home i have windows operating system. Is there any way to open iphone project codes like .h and .m files on windows through some converter n all? Coz at times i wish like going through codes back at home to expand knowledge.

Thanks in advance...!!!

Answer (score 6):

.h and .m files are just plain text. You should be able to open them with Wordpad.

If you want syntax highlighting, try [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net/uk/site.htm).